# How to get hidden iframe element in Cypress? And how to write in it?

Tags: cypress

I want to get/idenify hidden iframe element in Cypress and write something in there, like a text.

```html
<div class="tox-edit-area">
  <iframe id="tiny-react_36495184831607144646798_ifr" frameborder="0" 
     allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-0 for       
     help." class="tox-edit-area__iframe" __idm_frm__="1483" 
     __idm_id__="362838018">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

error fetched
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4wub.png

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried along with the errors that you faced.

Comment: Welcome, Anish! Please provide a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can get a better idea of the problem you're facing, what you've tried, and potentially what we can do to help.

Comment: @AlapanDas I have edited the question. Added error and HTML

Comment: @natn2323 please refer to the question again. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Go to `cypress/support/command.js` and write:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', (iframe) => {
    return cy.get(iframe)
        .its('0.contentDocument.body')
        .should('be.visible')
        .then(cy.wrap);
})
```

2.In the tests write:

```
cy.getIframe('.tox-edit-area__iframe').clear().type('Demo Text')
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It worked on my end. Thank you.